# Extract the last 2 bits from a byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to extract the hidden text from a .bmp file, and in order to do that i have to read it all and extract the last 2 bits of each byte and reassemble them. How do you extract the last 2 bits from each byte?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mask your byte with 0b00000011 using a bitwise and

```
0b00000011 & input_byte
```

For further information on bit manipulation in Python refer to [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation)

Comment: how am i going to do that though with all the bytes? i am kind of new in python so if you can be more specific that would be helpfull

Comment: You want to open your file call readall() to get all your bytes and loop over all of them